# Pattern to make many to many model creation in a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1

I am working with asp.net mvc 3. I have a scenario like this:

1. I have the User model and the Group model. A User can have many groups and a Group can have many users. Hence, it is a many to many relationship.
2. I have a UserController and a GroupController.
3. A User can create a new group.
4. I have UsersRepository and GroupsRepository as described in the repository pattern.
5. The GroupController has a Create(Group newGroup) action.
6. A User may not have more than 10 Groups.
7. The Group name must be unique.

Problem 1: to handle restriction 6, I must implement IValidatableObject on class User and generate a validation error if the User has more than 10 Groups. However, since the Create action of GroupController receives only the Group as a parameter, the model binder will never call User.Validate().

Problem 2: the only way to handle restriction 7 is to validate the new group name against all Groups already present on the Groups repository. Hence, this validation must be in GroupsRepository. Am I right about that?

Afterall, I feel like I am doing something wrong. My question is: on my scenario, what is the best way to implement the creation of a new Group by an existing User? Should I create a viewmodel like UserGrougViewModel and pass it on the Create action of GroupController? Or should I keep the Create(Group newGroup) action untouched and add a CreateGroup(User user) action on the UserController to validate the user against rule 6 and then redirect to action Create(Group newGroup) of the GroupController?

Answer (score 0):

***Problem1:***

Not sure about implementing IValidatableObject, but you could create a method in User repository that would return you a count of number of groups the user is in. And, call this function from GroupController's create method. Like this:

**USER REPOSITORY**

---

```
public int GetNumberOfGroupsByUserId(int userId)
{
   return context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u=>u.Id==userId).Groups.Count;
}
```

Usage from GroupController while creating new group

```
    UserRepository userRepo= new UserRepository();
    if(userRepo.GetNumberOfGroupsByUserId(id)>10)
    {
      //write code to send error message to view saying the user already has more than 10 groups
    }
else
{
 //go ahead and create new group
}
```

***Problem 2:***

> the only way to handle restriction 7 is to validate the new group name against all Groups already present on the Groups repository. Hence, this validation must be in GroupsRepository. Am I right about that?

No, the validation can still occur in your GroupController (or in your business layer). Just like in your problem 1, you could create a method in GroupRepository which returns `true` if the group name already exists in the database, otherwise false. The method would look something like this in GroupRepository

```
public bool NameExists(string groupName)
{
 int count=0;
count= context.Groups.Where(g=>g.Name==groupName).Count;
if (count==0)
return false;
else
return true;
}
```

Usage from GroupController while creating new group

```
        GroupRepository groupRepo= new GroupRepository();
        if(groupRepo.NameExists(groupName))
        {
          //write code to send error message to view saying a group already exists with same name
        }
    else
    {
     //go ahead and create new group
    }
```

Comment: It's a good solution but I personally don't like to validate inside the controller action. Furthermore, note that the creation of a new group needs to modify the user model by adding the new group to the user's list of groups. Therefore, the create action of the group controller is modifying the user, which is not good..

Comment: This was just an example showing how you can do validation outside of Repository. You can do validation in your business layer. I don't think repositories are good place for validation. My sample code does not modify User object at all. What do you mean when you said 'Therefore, the create action of the group controller is modifying the user, which is not good..'?

Comment: Wthat do you call a business layer? As I wrote, it's a many to many relationship. A user has many groups. Therefore, when a user creates a group, I need to add this created group in the user's list of groups in order to pin  the created group to the user. That's the whole problem... I don't know the best way to implement the creation of a group by an existing user.